# Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition?

Tags: calculus

$y(x+1)+y'=0$ , $y(-2)=1$

I don't understand what this question is telling me to do? Can someone please explain?

Comment: What function $\;y(x)\;$ fulfills the given conditions. That is what you are being asked. That is a differential equation.

Comment: Hint: The differential equation is separable

Comment: @smcc That's actually ambiguous. It could be $y \cdot (x+1)$ or $y$ evaluated at $x+1$. N.b., if the latter, the standard way to solve this is via the Laplace transform.

Comment: First solve it respect to $y$ then use from the given condition and find constant

Comment: @stochasticboy321 You could say the something about many other questions. I thought it was very likely not to be $y$ evaluated at $x+1$ because then the argument of $y'$ would also have been given explicitly (and because it is very obvious the person asking the question is not at that level).

Comment: @smcc Oh of course. It's just that I thought of the second possibility at first, and extrapolated to this being someone unfamiliar with the laplace transform technique and hence asking the question. Dunno why I tagged you, I wasn't calling you out or anything. Apologies if it seemed like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is asking you to find the general solution $y(x)$ to the differential equation and then to use the initial condition $y(-2)=1$ to determine the constant.

Since the equation is separable you can write it in the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=-y(x+1)$ and from there $\int\frac1ydy=\int-(x+1)dx$ you should be able to solve from here by integrating. A constant of integration will be introduced and that is why we have the intial condition $y(-2)=1$ to determine this constant.

Comment: So then I would have get: $ln|y|+C$ = $(-x^2)/2 -x +C$ which then becomes $ln|y|= (-x^2)/2 -x+ C$ and then do $e^ln|y|=e^(-x^2)/2 -x+ C$ ultimately getting $y= e^((-x^2)/2 -x))*K$ (K being some constant)

Comment: Yes and from here plug in $x=-2, y=1$ to find $K$.

Comment: So when I plug $x=-2, y=1$ my answer is 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear homogeneous ODE and can be solved using separation.
$$
y(x+1)+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0\\
y(x+1)=-\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\\
(x+1)\partial x=-\frac{\partial y}{y} , y\neq0\\
\int(x+1)\partial x=-\int\frac{\partial y}{y}, y\neq0\\
\frac{x^2}{2}+x+C=-\ln(y), y>0\\
-\frac{x^2}{2}-x+D=\ln(y), y>0\\
e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-x+D}=y, y>0\\
y=Ae^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-x},y>0
$$
now lets use $y(-2)=1$ and we get:
$$
1=Ae^{-\frac{(-2)^2}{2}-(-2)}=Ae^{-2+2}=Ae^{0}\Rightarrow A=1
$$
hence we get: $y=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-x}, y>0$

In case I've miscalculated, I believe you can understand the general technique of the solution.